# Python / SQLAlchemy - load relation when foreign key is updated?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a class:

```
class Chart(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'chart'
   id = C('chart_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
   element_id = C(Integer, ForeignKey('element.element_id'))
   element = relationship(Element)
   name = C(String)

   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
```

Usage is pretty common,

```
chart = Chart('Some name')
chart.element_id = element_id
```

But chart.element is None after setting element_id. Is there any way to auto-load this relation for new object before flush/commit?

Answer (score 6):

The best option is

```
chart = Chart('Some name')
chart.element = element
```

Assign direct object to the relation ship. If you are assign `element_id` then until it flush it will be in memory. Internally it will fire a query `SELECT * FROM ELEMENT WHERE ELEMENT.id = element_id` but that element_id data is not store or it will be in memory.

So i suggest direct assign object if you don't want to flush.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I'm using this way now. My function receives element_id, and I get element by myself to set it in a Chart object (flush is done internally). It looks it's the only one way.